# Syntax error on line that doesn't have a syntax error

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python just wonder why if the code below is not functioning
If anyone can point out what's the error?
this is the error code I'm getting

```
x.withdraw(wd_amt)
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self, name, balance=0.0,dec):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.dec = dec
        #self.d_amt = d_amt

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            raise RuntimeError('Amount greater than available balance.')
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance



user_name = raw_input("name?")
Bal_amount = int(raw_input("amount?"))
dec_1 = (raw_input("withdraw or deposit?"))
x = Customer(user_name,Bal_amount,dec_1)

def play():
    if dec_1 == "withdraw":
     wd_amt = int(raw_input('How much?')
     x.withdraw(wd_amt)
     print x.balance

    elif dec_1 == "deposit":
     dp_amt = int(raw_input('How much?')
     x.deposit(dp_amt)
     print x.balance    

play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unbalanced parentheses:

```
 wd_amt = int(raw_input('How much?')
```

and

```
 dp_amt = int(raw_input('How much?')
```

I was going to suggest to use `pyflakes` or `pylint` to help you catch these things, but they also just report a syntax error on the next line.

My suggestion to catch these things in the future is to always look at the immediate previous lines when you have a syntax error that doesn't seem to make sense.  Some editors might also make it more obvious with syntax highlighting.

When that doesn't work, start commenting out lines, starting with the one Python says the error is at.  If the error keeps moving, it is likely an issue farther up.  For example, if I comment out `x.withdraw(wd_amt)`, the error moves to the `print x.balance`.